# How to list/order a number of hospitals which have lat and long fields in the model on the basis of 25 km from customer's location in Django Rest?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm currently working in DRF and I have a data list of many hospitals which I can list. I need to order it on the basis of a 25km radius of the customer's location. Both the Hospital models and customer profiles have got latitude and longitude fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the approach you're looking for is [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield), it offers you spatial support, and will allow you to define fields like:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import PointField

class Hospital(models.Model):
    coordinates = PointField(
        geography=True,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

and considering your user also has a `coordinates` field, you could then do things like using [`distance_lte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance-lte):

```
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D

hospitals_within_25_km_radius = Hospital.objects.filter(
    coordinates__distance_lte=(user.coordinates, D(km=25))
)
```

or even [filtering and ordering by which hospitals are the closest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#distance):

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance

hospitals_within_25_km_ordered_by_closest = Hospital.objects.annotate(
    distance=Distance('coordinates', user.coordinates),
).filter(
    distance__lte=25000,
).order_by(
    'distance',
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use GeoDjango with MySQL?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#mysql-spatial-limitations
It is - but with limitations.